# adding property to UITableView subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

i'm creating `UITableViewCell` subclass which need to hold 3 types of images: facebook twitter and linkedin. the thing is that i need to know which service the cell support at the moment so i have try to add a property to the class called `service` which is `NSString`.

this is how i am setting up my cell to ad it to the table:

```
static NSString *sCellIdentifier = @"sCell";

SocialTableViewCell *sCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];

sCell.service = @"service";

if (sCell == nil){
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExampleView" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[SocialTableViewCell class]])
        {
            sCell = (SocialTableViewCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    sCell.serviceImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_Twitter.png"];
    sCell.service = @"twitter";
    return sCell;
}
```

i am trying to set the property like this :

```
sCell.service = @"twitter";
```

and when i am trying to read it from the `awakeFromNib` method in the `SocialTableViewCell` class i get null. what should i do to manage this?

Comment: The `awakeFromNib` method is called before you have set the `service` property.

Comment: ok so what method should i use? where can i read about it?

Comment: You can create a setter method for the `service` property and handle it there.

Comment: i think you should have a .m .h of your custom cell and handle it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `awakeFromNib` method is called before you have set the `service` property.

You could use the setter method of the `service` property :

```
-(void) setService:(NSString *)service {
   // Set the value to the internal iVar
   _service = service;

   // Here you can do what you want with the service value like
   self.titleLabel.text = service;
}
```

Comment: thanks! and where should i make a check what value the instance is holding? like a "viewdidload" method in uiviewcontroller

Comment: You can do that in the setter as well. There is not `viewDidLoad` for views.

Comment: i am trying to load buttons state from the value this property is holding... so i have some "loadButtons" method i want to call

Comment: Just call it from the setter method.